# bind:value on <select> unexpectedly causes (idempotent) update of another variable

Tags: svelte

Consider this code:

```
<script>
  let numbers = [
    {name: 'one', multiples: [1,2,3]},
    {name:'two', multiples: [2,4,6]},
    {name: 'three', multiples: [3,6,9]}
  ];
  let selectedNumber;
  let selectedMultiple;

  $: console.log("selectedNumber changed: ", selectedNumber?.name);
  $: console.log("selectedMultiple changed: ", selectedMultiple);
</script>

<select bind:value={selectedNumber}>
  {#each numbers as number}<option value={number}>{number.name}</option>{/each}
</select>
{#if selectedNumber}
<select bind:value={selectedMultiple}>
  {#each selectedNumber.multiples as multiple}<option>{multiple}</option>{/each}
</select>
{/if}
```

This creates a Select element with three options (`one`, `two`, and `three`). Choose any one of them, and another Select element appears showing multiples of that number (e.g. `3`, `6`, and `9`).

However, I was surprised to see that when I choose a new value with the second Select — which should only update `selectedMultiple` — `selectedNumber` (the variable bound to the first Select) is "updated" as well (meaning that reactive declarations involving it are rerun). You can see this by looking in the javascript console while playing with the two Selects.

Why is that? The second Select depends on the first one, but the first Select should not depend on the second one.

Comment: I think this is probably the same issue as https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4933 (also see [my comment](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4933#issuecomment-1383940183)) and seems to be specific to `bind:`. When you bind to a variable, anything that is deemed as a dependency, whether direct or indirect, is invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug. Svelte invalides things here that are only read:

```js
function select_change_handler() {
    selectedNumber = select_value(this);
    $$invalidate(0, selectedNumber);
    $$invalidate(2, numbers); // ???
}

function select_change_handler_1() {
    selectedMultiple = select_value(this);
    $$invalidate(1, selectedMultiple);
    $$invalidate(0, selectedNumber); // ?
}
```

In general Svelte errs on the side of invalidating more rather than missing potential changes. Not sure if there is any reasonable scenario where this would be necessary though.